# How to upload image directly to S3 with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

went on NPMJS but could't find any libraries useful. It looks like nearly all of them requires it first to be stored on the server then upload to S3. Any chance the file can be uploaded directly to S3?

Comment: There is an official SDK for that. Just google for it.

Answer (score 0):

These two links are good sources of uploads to S3.

http://blog.katworksgames.com/2014/01/26/nodejs-deploying-files-to-aws-s3/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

This blog post explains in detail how you can solve this problem:
https://www.terlici.com/2015/05/23/uploading-files-S3.html

You need to create a signed URL first and after that a user can upload a file **directly** to S3.